# jQuery loop ul li

Tags: jquery, xhtml

What's wrong with this?
I'm trying to hide all empty li.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#details li").each(function() {
            if ($(this).length == 0) {
                $(this).css({ display: "none" }); ;
            }
        });
    });
```

Markup:

```
<ul id="details">
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The lack of precision about what your problem is?

Comment: You should be more precise in your question because if we don't know what is the result that you want, it's difficult to suggest a solution.

Comment: You might want to read up on Stackoverflow markdown formatting - I don't think you meant to post the HTML like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) length, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#details li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().length == 0) {
      $(this).css({ display: "none" }); ;
    }
  });
});
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
$("#details li").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().length == 0;
}).hide();
```

Or a slightly different check that works for your purposes, courtesy of @[Rafael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80720/rafael):

```
$("#details li:empty").hide();
```

Comment: You should always `$.trim()` before checking length (due to whitespace in HTML).

Comment: @Marko - If there might be white-space yes do this...if you're *assured* there's not (can't tell from the example), same the regex calls :)

Comment: You can just do $('#details li:empty').hide();

Comment: @Rafael - `:empty` is a slightly different check, though it would work for the author's purpose, you're right.

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
if ($(this).is(':empty')) {}
```

Furthermore, you should be able to re-write the above code as:

```
$("#details li:empty").each(function() {
  $(this).css({ display: "none" });
});
```

Or even:

```
$("#details li:empty").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `$(this).length` cannot possibly be zero.